# Error layout vs error500.ctp in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I noticed that for some exceptions, cake will render the View/Errors/error400(or 500).ctp and for others it will discard the default layout and render the View/Layouts/error.ctp

I would like to know all cases the error layout gets rendered and why.

So far I found this:

Missing Controller | View/Errors/error
Missing View         | View/Errors/error
Missing Table        | View/Layouts/error
Fatal Error             | blank page

From the looks of it I would say, that all error500 will get the layout. But this would mean, that the `View/Errors/error500.ctp` would never be rendered and that seems not logical.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for all errors. This will set layout to `error`.
In your `AppController.php`

```
function beforeRender() { 
    if ($this->name == 'CakeError') { 
       $this->layout = "error"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
But that doesn't answer my question what exceptions force cake to switch to the error layout automatically.